# What does sw stand for in the command line utility sw_vers (sw underscore vers)

Tags: terminal

I have been using the command `sw_vers -productVersion` to find out the version of the OS I'm using. Just wondering if anyone knew what sw was an acronym for?

Comment: I'd guess software....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sw_vers.1.html) doesn't actually state it I'd be willing to guess it's '**S**oft**w**are'

Comment: Given "print Mac OS X operating system version information" I would have expected its name to be `os_vers` :)

Comment: @DavidPostill and if you ported it to linux you'd need to rename it to linux_vers? :) Or are we saying os as in operating system.... in which case it's Mac Operating System X operating system version information? ;)